# How to implement a wrap around index?

Tags: algorithm

I want a wrap around index like 1232123...., and the frame size is 3. How to implement it? Does it has a term?

```rust
for i in 1..100 {
   let idx = loop_index(i);
   print!("{} ", idx);
}
```

Expected output for frame 3:

```
1 2 3 2 1 2 3 2 1...
```

Expected output for frame 4:

```
1 2 3 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 3 2 1...
```

Comment: Can you think of how the [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo) might help you achieve this?

Comment: Modulo can get  a loop like 1 2 3 1 2 3

Comment: Cound up and than count down and than repeat the sequence every 2n-2 indexes,

Comment: It's not called wrap-around (that would just be modulo). I've seen it referred to as ping-pong but there probably isn't an official term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a size of 3, notice that the sequence 1232 has length 4, and then it repeats. In general, for size `n`, the length is `2*(n-1)`. If we take the modulo `i % (2*(n-1))`, the task becomes simpler: turn a sequence `0123..(2*(n-1)-1)` into `123..(n-1)n(n-1)..321`. And this can be done using `abs` and basic arithmetic:

```
n = 3
r = 2 * (n - 1)
for i in range(20):
    print(n - abs(n - (i % r)) - 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

When you reach the top number, you start decreasing; when you reach the bottom number, you start increasing.

Don't change direction until you reach the top or bottom number.

```py
def count_up_and_down(bottom, top, length):
    assert(bottom < top)
    direction = +1
    x = bottom
    for _ in range(length):
        yield x
        direction = -1 if x == top else +1 if x == bottom else direction
        x = x + direction

for i in count_up_and_down(1, 4, 10):
    print(i, end=' ')
# 1 2 3 4 3 2 1 2 3 4
```

Alternatively, combining two `range`s with `itertools`:

```py
from itertools import chain, cycle, islice

def count_up_and_down(bottom, top, length):
    return islice(cycle(chain(range(bottom, top), range(top, bottom, -1))), length)

for i in count_up_and_down(1, 4, 10):
    print(i, end=' ')
# 1 2 3 4 3 2 1 2 3 4
```